# Understanding pointer indirection for accessing static variables in Cortex M0 firmware

Tags: ghidra, arm

I'm reverse engineering some firmware from a device running an ARM Cortex M0 (specifically, Nordic nrf51802). For reference, the pertinent part of the memory map looks like this:

[image: memory map snippet]

I'm trying to add proper data types and names to global variables, but I don't quite understand what is going on.

Consider this simple bit of C code:

```
static volatile u32_t wait_for_ack_timeout_us;

static void update_radio_bitrate(void)
{
    NRF_RADIO->MODE = esb_cfg.bitrate << RADIO_MODE_MODE_Pos;

    switch (esb_cfg.bitrate) {
    case NRF_ESB_BITRATE_2MBPS:
        wait_for_ack_timeout_us = RX_ACK_TIMEOUT_US_2MBPS;
        break;

    case NRF_ESB_BITRATE_1MBPS:
        wait_for_ack_timeout_us = RX_ACK_TIMEOUT_US_1MBPS;
        break;

    case NRF_ESB_BITRATE_250KBPS:
        wait_for_ack_timeout_us = RX_ACK_TIMEOUT_US_250KBPS;
        break;

    case NRF_ESB_BITRATE_1MBPS_BLE:
        wait_for_ack_timeout_us = RX_ACK_TIMEOUT_US_1MBPS_BLE;
        break;

    default:
        /* Should not be reached */
    }
}
```

Ghidra decompiles this as:

[image]

Double-clicking PTR_DAT_00003d24 reveals:

[image]

Double-clicking DAT_2000003c here reveals where `wait_for_ack_timeout_us` actually lives in memory:

[image]

I changed the data type to uint32_t and added the variable name, but the decompiled code still shows the weird pointer dereference.

[image]

My questions are:

1. Why is there the added level of pointer indirection to access the static variable? Is this just how statics are implemented in ARM?
2. Ultimately what I'd like to get is decompiler output that looks like this:

```
void update_radio_bitrate(void)

{
  char cVar1;
  
  *(uint *)(PTR_NRF_RADIO_Type_40001000.RESERVED6[59]_00003d20 + 0x10) =
       (uint)(byte)PTR_nrf_esb_config_00003d1c[8];
  cVar1 = PTR_nrf_esb_config_00003d1c[8];
  if (cVar1 == '\0') {
    wait_for_ack_timeout_us = 0x40;
  }
  else if (cVar1 == '\x01') {
    wait_for_ack_timeout_us = 0x30;
  }
  else if (cVar1 == '\x02') {
    wait_for_ack_timeout_us = 0xfa;
  }
  else if (cVar1 == '\x03') {
    wait_for_ack_timeout_us = 0x40;
  }
  return;
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Right click PTR_DAT_00003d24 and retype it to be a pointer** and it should show up correctly